# How to get the user's location only with ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, location, flutter-packages

I want to know is there any way to get user's latitude and longitude with only ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission and not ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION?
I tried getting these two parameters with [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) and [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) without the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, but it didn't work.
Here you can see my code where I tried to get lat and lon with geolocator. When I add the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to my Manifest, It works perfectly, but when I remove it, it doesn't work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class geoLocator extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_geoLocatorState createState() => _geoLocatorState();
}


class _geoLocatorState extends State<geoo> {

var lat;
var lon;

Future _getCurrentLocation() async {

Position position;
try {
  position =
  await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

if (position != null) {
  setState(() {
    lat = position.latitude;
    lon = position.longitude;
  });
}

}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_getCurrentLocation();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        Text(lat.toString()),
        Text(lon.toString()),
        SizedBox(height: 20,),
        RaisedButton(onPressed: _getCurrentLocation, child: Text("Get Location"),),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: you can't , I had this problem with cofebazaar permissons they don't accept my app because of this permission, you must convince them that you really need this for some important reasons

Comment: Exactly, I have the same problem. So were you able to convince them that you need this permission?

Comment: why do you need this permission? if you have route tracking or sth like that you can convince them, but if you use this permission for sth like auto-location-find they will not accept! I had auto-location-find button in my app and they cause to remove this feature ! actually it works in some devices but not in all devices